# Confluency or confluence, which term is correct to describe the % area covered by cells?

Tags: terminology, cell-culture

I noticed that both of them are used in many scientific papers. Are these two terms, or can they be used interchangeably?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Comment: @rg255 Why is this off topic? It seems to be a valid terminology question.

Comment: Because it's an English language problem as far as I cam tell

Comment: also possibly duplicate http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29857/what-does-confluency-mean

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Origin of term ‘confluency’ in cell culture](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29857/origin-of-term-confluency-in-cell-culture)

Answer (score 2):

Searching Google Scholar for [cell confluence](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=confluence%20cell&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) returns 239000 hits, while searching for [cell confluency](https://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=confluency%20cell&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5) returns 75000 hits.

A look at the context in which they are used supports my gut feel, which is that

1:  "**confluence**" should be used in contexts of "% confluence"

2:  "**confluency**" should be used in contexts where you describe high or low levels of confluency.

Comment: I have conducted a thorough examination of this and find nothing to support your gut feeling, I am afraid. I have documented this in [a late answer to an earlier question on this topic.](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29857/origin-of-term-confluency-in-cell-culture/93287#93287)

Answer (score 1):

I have documented the history and current usage of the terms *confluence* and *confluency* in cell culture in an [answer to another question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29857/origin-of-term-confluency-in-cell-culture/93287#93287) specifically about the term *confluency*. As the current question has not been marked a duplicate of that one, and I believe the one answer posted to be incorrect, I am providing a brief answer here and direct the reader to my other answer for full supporting evidence.

> Q. Are confluence and confluency two [different] terms, or can they be
> used interchangeably?
>
> A. **Confluence** and **confluency**, as used in cell culture, have **exactly
> the same meaning**, and usage is a purely a matter of personal preference.

**Confluence** is a standard English word dating from the fifteenth century, and used as an abstract concept or applied to different phenomena in various fields. **Confluency** is a term almost exclusively used in relation to cell culture. In this respect, the definition from the short [Wikipedia entry on **confluency** (sic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluency) is pertinent:

> In cell culture biology, **confluence** (sic) refers to the percentage of the
> surface of a culture dish that is covered by adherent cells. For
> example, 50 percent confluence means roughly half of the surface is
> covered, while 100 percent confluence means the surface is completely
> covered by the cells, and no more room is left for the cells to grow
> as a monolayer.

While there is no guarantee that this Wikipedia entry is correct, it reflects the fact that (1) since the 1960s some authors have used one term and other authors have used the other term to mean the same thing (2) that the same authors have used their preferred term in relation to both the concept itself (without any numerical qualification) and with a percentage qualifier.

I have inspected recent papers in the Journal of Cell Science (referenced in note (9) of [my other answer](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/29857/origin-of-term-confluency-in-cell-culture/93287#93287) and found that both usages, as above, are still current, as well as mixed usage of both the type prescribed by @MarchHo (confluency, but 50% confluence) and the opposite (confluence, but 50% confluency).

Both terms are accepted by all journals I have looked at, and I have failed to find a pronouncement on the topic by any standards organization or professional body.

**Recommendation**

Use whatever the people with whom you work use. If you are starting out on your own, make your choice depending on your attitude to the English language or the respect you have for a particular pioneer of cell culture. But, whatever you choose, *never tell anyone else that they **should** do the same*.